# change element within nodeset using stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have this stylesheet which takes an empty input.

and needs to produce the output as

```
    <result>
        <Customers>
            <customer name="FirstName">John</customer>
            <customer name="FirstName">Kevin</customer>
        </Customers>
    </result>
```

And this result I'm specifying in the xsl for now is which I will get from some other service call in this same stylesheet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:variable name="request">
            <result>
                <Customers>
                    <customer name="Name">John</customer>
                    <customer name="Name">Kevin</customer>
                </Customers>
            </result>
        </xsl:variable>

            <xsl:apply-templates select="$request/result/Customers"/>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node( ) | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node( )"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="customer/@name[. = 'Name']">
        <xsl:attribute name="name">FirstName</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But there is an error while calling template. What is wrong in my stylesheet?

Comment: You've tagged this both `xslt-1.0` and `xslt-2.0` but the tags are meant to be mutually exclusive. The above XSLT will only work correctly in XSLT 2.0, not in XSLT 1.0. (In XSLT 1.0, the `$request` variable is a result tree fragment, and would need to be converted to a node-set by an extension function). Does your XSLT processor definitely support XSLT 2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you say `which takes an empty input`? No, an XSLT only works when supplied with an XML input(it may be as small as this: `<r/>`), but it must have an XML input. Everything else looks fine.. But as per your expected output, the apply-templates shall be like

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="$request/result"/>
```